# Restlet Router Relative Path Error

Tags: java, http, rest, restlet

I am having an opposite error of what's written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728004/not-found-404-error-in-restlet).

I'm just trying to run a very simple sample application of Restlet in Eclipse.

**MailServerApplication.java**

```
public class MailServerApplication extends Application {

    /**
     * Launches the application with an HTTP server.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            The arguments.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server mailServer = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8111);
        mailServer.setNext(new MailServerApplication());
        mailServer.start();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public MailServerApplication() {
        setName("RESTful Mail Server");
        setDescription("Example for 'Restlet in Action' book");
        setOwner("Restlet S.A.S.");
        setAuthor("The Restlet Team");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a root Router to dispatch call to server resources.
     */
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("http://localhost:8111/", 
                RootServerResource.class);
        router.attach("http://localhost:8111/accounts/",
                AccountsServerResource.class);
        router.attach("http://localhost:8111/accounts/{accountId}",
                AccountServerResource.class);
        return router;
    }
}
```

**RootServerResource.java**

```
public class RootServerResource 
    extends ServerResource implements RootResource {

    public String represent() {
        return "This is the root resource";
    }

    public String describe() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

**RootResource.java**

```
/**
 * Root resource.
 */
public interface RootResource {

    /**
     * Represents the application root with a welcome message.
     * 
     * @return The root representation.
     */
    @Get("txt")
    public String represent();

}
```

The code works perfectly as is if I'm running the server locally and if I type the full uri including the localhost on my browser "localhost:8111". However, as soon as I change my router declaration to be router, the page always throws a 404 error.

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/", RootServerResource.class); 
    router.attach("/accounts/", AccountsServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/accounts/{accountId}", AccountServerResource.class);
    return router;
}
```

So in other words, if I attach a full path including the http and the ip address to the router, it works correctly but the relative path doesn't.

This is pretty bizzare. If there's any error, I would've assumed that the relative definition should work and the localhost definition shouldn't, but what I'm experiencing is the exact opposite. Any suggestions?

Edit:

Upon request, I'm including my AccountServerResource.class

```
/**
 * Implementation of a mail account resource.
 */
public class AccountServerResource extends ServerResource implements
        AccountResource {

    /** The account identifier. */
    private int accountId;

    /**
     * Retrieve the account identifier based on the URI path variable
     * "accountId" declared in the URI template attached to the application
     * router.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
        this.accountId = Integer.parseInt(getAttribute("accountId"));
    }

    public String represent() {
        return AccountsServerResource.getAccounts().get(this.accountId);
    }

    public void store(String account) {
        AccountsServerResource.getAccounts().set(this.accountId, account);
    }

    public void remove() {
        AccountsServerResource.getAccounts().remove(this.accountId);
    }
}
```

And the AccountResource interface:

```
/**
 * User account resource.
 */
public interface AccountResource {

    /**
     * Represents the account as a simple string with the owner name for now.
     * 
     * @return The account representation.
     */
    @Get("txt")
    public String represent();

    /**
     * Stores the new value for the identified account.
     * 
     * @param account
     *            The identified account.
     */
    @Put("txt")
    public void store(String account);

    /**
     * Deletes the identified account by setting its value to null.
     */
    @Delete
    public void remove();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are running restlet in `standalone` mode. To be more specific `MailServerApplication` has main-method from which you are running restlet.

To fix the issue, you need to make your web-container understand the details of your  `Application`.

Here is a skeleton version of the code needed for you to run. This way, you **need not** mention the `IP`, `Port` details in the url-binding (this example uses Jetty, you could as well use tomcat):

**MyApplication.java**:

```
package com.sample;

import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Context;
import org.restlet.Request;
import org.restlet.Response;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.representation.StringRepresentation;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication() {
        super();
    }

    public MyApplication(Context parentContext) {
        super(parentContext);
    }

    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        router.attach("/hello", HelloResource.class);

  Restlet mainpage = new Restlet() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                stringBuilder.append("<html>");
                stringBuilder.append("<head><title>Hello Application " +
                        "Servlet Page</title></head>");
                stringBuilder.append("<body bgcolor=white>");
                stringBuilder.append("<a href=\"app/hello\">hello</a> --> returns hello world message " +
                        "and date string");
                stringBuilder.append("</body>");
                stringBuilder.append("</html>");
                response.setEntity(new StringRepresentation(
                        stringBuilder.toString(),
                        MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
            }
        };
        router.attach("", mainpage);

        return router;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

         <servlet>
                 <servlet-name>Restlet</servlet-name>
                 <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
                 <init-param>
                         <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
                         <param-value>com.sample.MyApplication</param-value>
                 </init-param>
         </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Restlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**HelloResource.java**:

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.restlet.Context;
import org.restlet.Request;
import org.restlet.Response;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.representation.StringRepresentation;
import org.restlet.representation.Variant;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class HelloResource extends ServerResource {

    public HelloResource() {
        super();
    }
    public HelloResource(Context context,
                          Request request,
                          Response response) {     
        getVariants().add(new Variant(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
    }

    @Override
    protected Representation get() throws ResourceException {
        String message = "Hello World!" +
        " \n\nTime of request is:"
        + Calendar.getInstance()
        .getTime().toString();

        return new StringRepresentation(message,
        MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>testwar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
           <id>maven-restlet</id>
           <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
           <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>numberformat-releases</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/numberformat/20130213/master/repo</url>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.simple</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0.v20091005</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>        
                <groupId>github.numberformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>blog-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                <gitUrl>https://github.com/numberformat/20110220</gitUrl>
                </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>1</id>
                <phase>site</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>            
              </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>testwar</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

Goto the project's root folder and execute using: `mvn clean compile jetty:run`

Hope this helps